# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS highlight color for dialog buttons is too little visible

Tags: 18.04, themes, appearance, button, window-buttons

In Ubuntu 18.04 LTS it's so difficult to see which button is the current selection in a dialog window, because it's too little visible the color highlight.

Using the mouse it's easy, but moving through buttons with the keyboard is challenging.

You can see that in this screenshot, where the current selection is on the "Salva" button (it's with orange border).

[image]

It's normal?

How to enhance the current selection?

It's a shame that the single user must correct design-bug like that... it should be made by the Ubuntu team.

Thanks.

Comment: See if [Increase the highlighted button bezel thickness (GNOME)](https://askubuntu.com/a/1121550/248158) meets your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I confirm it is a pain to make a difference between the buttons.**

I did what was suggested [increase the highlighted button bezel thickness (GNOME)](https://askubuntu.com/a/1121550/248158)

```
vi ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
```

Add the following to the file gtk.css (make a backup if unsure):

```
button {
    outline-style: solid;
    outline-offset: -2px;
    outline-width: 2px;
    outline-radius: 2px;
}
```

Create the directory if not present.

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/gtk-3.0
```

Save the file 'gtk-3.0', logout and login.

Then it is much more readable. Have a look to the screen dump attached.[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try it as soon as possible. It's a shame that the single user must correct design-bug like that... it should be made by the Ubuntu team.

Comment: It works! Thansk a lot!

Comment: see also my answer, it may help you

Comment: Bug ? It is maybe too much. I am surprised that much more people didn't complain that the selected button is not more visible...

Answer (score 1):

[Rudy Vissers' answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1208697/502687) works well, but will affect all elements that may have an outline. This causes the outline to also appear on the checkbox and radio elements, such as the browser prompt to download a file.

The solution is to apply the css only to the buttons:

```
button {
    outline-style: solid;
    outline-offset: -2px;
    outline-width: 2px;
    outline-radius: 2px;
}
```

Comment: You are right. 'button' is more precise. Will try it and then correct the answer.

Comment: I have tried to apply the CSS to the button only and it is what is desired. I have adapted the answer.