# GNOME 3 active button color

Tags: 18.04, gnome, appearance, button, borders

the active button border is so thin I can barely see it (see attached image). Is there a way to change this to a thicker border or to a fully colored active button?

[image: button border color]

Comment: its a duplicate question.. just finding the link..@DKBose can help to provide link..

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1120993/increase-the-highlighted-button-bezel-thickness-gnome/